# Odds of a given Windows EventID to be unique for a Source?

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, nagios

I am using the [basic NRPE plugins](http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Uncategorized/Operating-Systems/Windows-NRPE/Basic-NRPE_NT-Plugins/details) for Nagios to passively monitor Windows Eventlog. The plugin allows for an EventID exception list as a command argument. So, for instance, I can block any event that has an EventID of 1024.

Of course, this doesn't look at the source of the event.

What I am wondering is on the chance of two Sources using the same EventID. Some spot checking(googling the eventid) has found only uniqueness, so it might be an acceptable risk, but I would like your thoughts. Have you ever come across two sources that use the same EventID?

Comment: Here's your answer - https://www.google.com/#output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=event+id+1024&oq=event+id+1024&gs_l=hp.3..0l4.1444.4456.0.4673.13.12.0.1.1.0.142.1027.10j2.12.0....0...1c.1.23.psy-ab..0.13.975.JiBlfw612z4&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.49967636,d.dmg&fp=6acc75de4afeeb84&biw=1680&bih=910

Comment: Have you ever come across two sources that use the same EventID?

Comment: My Google link shows at least four Sources that generate Event ID 1024, as just one example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no restriction on event sources using any ID the programmer decides. To give a concrete example, my [`ts_block`](https://github.com/EvanAnderson/ts_block) script (source "ts_block"), for example, uses event IDs 1, 2, 3, 256, and 257. A search of those event IDs in a public event database (like-- and I hold my nose as I say this-- [eventid.net](http://eventid.net)) will show you many, many other sources that use these same event IDs.

If you're comparing only on the event ID then you're not comparing on enough.